# Why is CrudRepository ignoring a @Column?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have an object model that looks like this:

```
public class Agreement {
    @Id @Column(name = "AGREEMENT_ID") private String agreementId;

    @Column(name = "RATE") private String rate;
    @Column(name = "NOTE") private String note;
    ... // A number of other fields
}
```

Each field has getters and setters, as generated by IntelliJ, verified these are all correct. On my GUI, the user has the option to make changes to an agreement, then hit "Save". Now my server needs to make the update on the back end. I'm using Spring Repositories and so I have:

```
@Repository
public interface AgreementRepository extends CrudRepository<Agreement, String> {}
```

When the user makes the submission I invoke `agreementRepository.save(agreement)`. However, one of my fields, `rate` is not being updated on the back end.

I have stepped through the code and verified that the `rate` property is set correctly in the `agreement` object being passed to `save()`. Further, I have printed the SQL and verified that it is in fact at this level that the issue seems to be occurring, noting the `save()` method is calling a `SELECT` followed by `UPDATE` as expected since I'm modifying the same entry over and over in testing, but I can see clearly in the `UPDATE` part of the query that the `rate` field is not being set.

Odder still, ALL other fields are being set properly, regardless of whether I am also setting `RATE` or not. All other changes are propagating through just fine. There is nothing unusual about this `RATE` field. I thought maybe there was a bad trigger or something that a developer before me had put in, but I can see that the `UPDATE` SQL generated by Spring is clearly not setting it, and have verified no such triggers exist.

What is the reason that `CrudRepository.save()` would ignore one of my fields? It is not marked `@Transient` and is not unusual in any way. If it is not `CrudRepository` where else should I look to see why this field is not being set correctly?

Comment: Which database are you using? Did you check that the "RATE" column exists in the database?

Comment: So the other columns are updated and rate, doesn't it? Have you @transactional annotation?

Comment: RATE column exists, is a `VARCHAR(128)` (more than enough), and is `nullable`. I have tried marking the calling method as `@Transactional` and this achieved the same effect. But yes, the other columns update just fine.

Comment: what implementation of spring data are you using? If you're using JPA, then i believe the underlying entitymanager (i.e. hibernate) is the one responsible for generating the queries, not CrudRepository. Some of the entitymanagers will know if the field has indeed changed and only update the fields that changed. Even if the setter is called but the value is set is equivalent to the old value, the its likely that it will not perform the update operation on that field. However, i suspect this is not the case for you.

Comment: @loesak I'm using JPA, even so, I'm noting that these changes are occurring just fine in other fields, and further I am changing the value of this field from test to test, so even if for some reason it's in a detached state and not comparing against the DB, whatever is in memory should also be different. Messing around with changing the field name now

Comment: @mike without more information, not sure if i can help. I would definitely double verify that the getter method for rate is being generated as i believe if it is not, then its likely that the field wont get picked up. You may also want to annotate your class with the Entity annotation (not that its going to fix your issue). You'll likely have to find the code that scans the entity to determine what query to build to find out the answer.

Comment: I've answered this question below, it's a bizarre one. I tried a few `mvn clean` just in case, as that sometimes fixes issues, but it wasn't until I restarted my IDE that things began behaving as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the really wild part. It seems my issue was resolved by restarting IntelliJ. Really having a hard time understanding what went wrong.

I started by renaming the column in the DB to something else but leaving all other configs the same. I noted that no exception was being thrown and tried to figure out why, Spring Repository should be yelling at me for mis-configured entities. After a few more bizarre occurrences, I thought it would be best to restart IntelliJ, just in case.

Suddenly it correctly picked up the column was not correctly named. I renamed the column back to what it should be and everything is working as expected. Really bizarre.